# Setting specifies the context site for experience editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I am working on multisites and I want to open experience editor for the context site, but  sitecore doesn't resolve the context site and it always takes me to the default website, there is a setting in sitecore.config file i set it to "true", but still it takes me to the default website :

http://mywebsite.local/?sc_mode=edit&sc_site=website

here is the setting in sitecore.config, my sitecore version is 8.1 (Update 2)

```
<!--  PREVIEW - RESOLVE SITE
            If false, the Preview.DefaultSite setting specifies the context site to use when a user previews an item.
            If true, when a user previews an item, Sitecore tries to resolve the root item and the context site based on the current content language
            and the path to the item. If Sitecore cannot resolve the context site, it uses the site that is specified in the Preview.DefaultSite setting.
            Default value: false (use the value of the Preview.DefaultSite setting)
      -->
    <setting name="Preview.ResolveSite" value="true"/>
```

Comment: have you seen this: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/382913 ?

Comment: @MarekMusielak : I applied this fix but still i have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This Reported as bug in Sitecore 8.1 (Update 2), and this is the fix from support team :

1. Open the “/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/ContentEditing/ExperienceEditor” item in the core database
2. Change the “Link” field value to:
   /?sc_mode=edit&sc_resolvelanguage=0

**Updated Answer :**

For multi-sites, you need to apply anothor fix I did not find its number on https://kb.sitecore.net/ so i uploaded the required files on dropbox :

1. Download **Sitecore.Support.88883.zip**, from this **[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mbvqfoho44w1g84/Sitecore.Support.88883.zip?dl=0)**
2. Copy the attached **Sitecore.Support.88883.dll** file to the /bin folder of your website;
3. Copy the attached **Sitecore.Support.88883.config** file to App_Config/Include folder of your website;
4. Open the "/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/ContentEditing/ExperienceEditor" item in the core database
5. Change the “Link” field value to: /?sc_mode=edit&sc_resolvelanguage=1
6. Clear the browser cache.

Comment: this did not resolve correctly for a multisite goverend by a virtual site definition list

Answer (score 0):

I have also face this issue before and it is known bug in sitecore. I have tried approach mentioned in below article. (However I am still facing this issue intermittently whenever I copy new dll in sitecore website.)

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/382913

**I have already placed all the files at my one drive link. Please take a backup of your existing file ("WebEditRibbon.aspx ) before replacing**

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AotVzR-_yI5ObO5-Pzq02mcx-EU